# CSS Align Paragraphs Horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have several paragraphs under a certain class that I want to align horizontally. Basically, I want each paragraph to have its own column.

I used `float: right;`. which made them into columns, but then it brought them out of formatting with the rest of the webpage.

Any tips on different ways to create columns, or to format with `float` would be appreciated.

Comment: Paragraphs themselves should not be columns. Use a wrapping element.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use CSS columns.

```
div
{
   -webkit-column-count:3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
   column-count:3;
   -webkit-column-gap:40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -moz-column-gap:40px; /* Firefox */
   column-gap:40px;
}
```

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp).

Or you could do it with list items if you're always going to have control over the text.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>paragraph</li>
    <li>paragraph</li>
    <li class="last">paragraph</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 30%
    margin-right: 5%;
}

ul li.right {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461105/css-columns-vs-floating-columns

Comment: that has an interesting result. there are 3 paragraphs that I want to make into columns. Before your code they were simply stacked on top of each other. After entering your code, I got a grid of text. The top 3 squares is the text of the first paragraph, the middle 3 are the second paragraph, the bottom the third.
So, your code worked in giving me columns, but I want each paragraph to have its own column. Any idea how that would work?